# Windows 8 RP doesn't start: 0xc0000428

Tags: windows-8-preview, bcd

My DVD Drive is broken, so I needed another option to install Windows 8.
What i've tried is to create a VMWare machine assigned to a phisical drive and installed Windows 8 RP. Within VMWare this machine starts with no trouble. With EasyBCD i've added the installtion from that partition to the boot. But when I select Windows 8 RP when the notebook starts up, i get the following message: 
File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
Status: 0xc0000428
Information: Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file.

I've tried to set the option 'Allow installtion of unsigned drivers on 64-Bit Windows' from EasyBCD but it doesn't solve te problem. I also can't get into the F8 menu of that specific installtion.

Can anybody give me advise how to solve this problem?

Comment: I know about installing from an USB drive but that's not an option for me.

Comment: Replace the DVD drive then.

Comment: @WesleyLalieu why can't you use a USB drive to install it?